# Remove Linked List Elements, My is basic but make me confused deeply

Tags: java

Solved it but still do not understand these basic part of ListNode(Question description attached below):

1.Is "1->2->3->3->4->5->3" a standard expression of ListNode in Java?  The parameter in removeElements is "head" and it looks like a node how can it possibly input a ListNode, or is that a "nested" ListNode?

2.The "removeElements" function "return" "dummy.next" and it has the same type as the first input argument. But in the while loop, a obj.next is definitely a Node(I thought), when it comes to "return" statement, it obviously return a type just like "1->2->3->3->4->5->3" , how can that possibly be?

Remove Linked List Elements
Example
Given 1->2->3->3->4->5->3, val = 3, you should return the list as 1->2->4->5

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    /**
     * @param head a ListNode
     * @param val an integer
     * @return a ListNode
     */
    public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
        // Write your code here
        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        dummy.next = head;
        head = dummy;
        while (head.next != null) {
            if (head.next.val == val) {
                head.next = head.next.next;
            } else {
                head = head.next;
            }
        }
        return dummy.next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - There is no standart ListNode class in Java.

2 - `obj.next` is not a `Node` but a `ListNode`. You an see it in the commented field. ListNode class has a member next with type ListNode.

Actually `removeElements` method is not returning something like: `1->2->3->3->4->5->3` but it just return 1. All elements like 1,2,3,3,.. are a ListNode and you can access the other with next.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  Here is my conclusion based on your illumination : the input type: "1->2->3->3->4->5->3"  is some kind of expression only be used in OJ system, and it can be recognized also if we build a function that accept this kind of input just like the OJ did.  Is that correct?  The data structure is kind of tool for us to use. the ListNode in algorithm book insert node one by one, not use "->" . So construct a method addNode or insertNode to put node to a ListNode one by one is pretty much the most common way we use. Is that  also correct?

Comment: What is OJ system? Your under standing is mostly correct. ListNode is actually a Node. You dont add a node to it. You create a LinkNode for each element in "1->2->3->3->4->5->3"  and set the next element as next for previous. Like: LinkNode node1 = new LinkNode(1); NodeLink node2 = new LinkNode(2); node1.next = node2; etc.

Comment: yeah, that part of knowledge is clear for me now. Thanks!  Btw, OJ I refer to is abbr. for Online Judge,  or Leetcode Online Judge. Just to let you know.